# How to focus last object in scrollview in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollview

I have a scrollView, where the clones of prefabs will generate horizontally. Here I wanted to focus last generated clone. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the position of the scroll rect. IN your case I'd guess you want to set it to 1:

```
myScrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition = 1f;
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect-horizontalNormalizedPosition.html

Comment: Thank you it is working as I wanted, Sorry I just misplaced earlier.